# Testability analysis for PHP

Tags: tools, unit-tests, php, testability

Is there any tool that reports on the testability of a PHP codebase?

I'm familiarised with what makes the code unit-testable, but I need a way to visualize it so I can easily find which classes can already be tested, and which ones will need some refactoring (and how much of it).

I'm pretty sure there are several tools for the job for other languages, but I can't find anything for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was no tool to do what I needed, I wrote one.

https://github.com/edsonmedina/php_testability

Comment: Hi there, great package, thank you so much for it, I've been using it for training my team, in recent installations I noticed the message from composer: **Package edsonmedina/php_testability is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.** Why is that?

Comment: @Anfelipe I haven't manintained it in years. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

How about the [PHP Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/), it generates all kinds of metrics about the code.

Although its focus is not test-ability I think cleaning up the "mess" will lead to much better testable code. Since its a [rules](http://phpmd.org/rules/index.html) based system and open-source you could add more rules that are test-ability specific, maybe its possible to borrow rules from other products.

Comment: My problem with phpmd is the abstractness of all the metrics it outputs. Also, I looked around about creating my own metrics, but couldn't find anything relevant. Do you have any links you could share?

Comment: @EdsonMedina, what do you mean by the "abstractness"? Any example would help me understand.

Comment: Maybe I'm being unfair, but metrics like code complexity, coupling between objects and such sound interesting but not so useful. It's hard to go through the code and find stuff that is easy to test right now by interpreting those numbers. Maybe there should be a combined metric (testability) and a issue browser for what's making the code hard to test. 
Am I reinventing the wheel or thinking wrong?

Comment: Why are you looking for stuff that is easy to test? Isn't it wiser to focus on parts that are complex and high risk. If you write tests now, its easier to refactor later.

Comment: I'm training a team into unit-testing. They have to start somewhere! 
But either way, having a tool telling me what issues I must fix to make the code testable would be killer.

Comment: FYI, PHPMD is no longer maintained: https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/).  It has some good code complexity metrics.  Since code complexity generally translates to test-ability, it will give you a good idea which areas of the code need refactoring.

It also gives you some metrics on unit-test coverage.  I find the historical aspect of this metric to be helpful.  As code is added and/or refactored, I like to see the overall percentage of unit test coverage to increase or at least stay the same.  If the overall test coverage is decreasing, I know there is too much coding going on without unit testing.

Comment: Doesn't SonarQube use the ouput of PHPMD?

Comment: I can't say for certain because I'm not that familiar with the inner workings of SonarQube, but based on the fact that SonarQube supports plug-ins for several different programming languages, I'm guessing no.